# How to filter column values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table called **Stage**. This table consists with ID,Owner1,Owner2,Owner3,Owner4 and Owner.
Owner 1-4 are different Stages. Owner column contains combination of Owner 1-4.

Stage Table as Below

[image]

I create a Separate table called **Ownership** in Power BI.
This table contains Distinct values of Owner 1-4.
I use below DAX query to populate Ownership table.

**Table = UNION(Values(Stage[Owner1]), Values(Stage[Owner2]), Values(Stage[Owner3]), Values(Stage[Owner4]))**

Then I create a Power BI Report.
I use **Ownership** Table data as a filter. and I use **Stage** table data as a report data.
this report contain only 2 column.
column 1 is ID(Stage), column 2 is Owner (Stage)

**My power BI Report Out put as below.**

[image]

If I select CUT but it display PRESS and ADD Values also.
I just want to remove  PRESS and ADD record.
and display only CUT Value

Final Out Put should as below

[image]

And if I select CUT and PRESS from the drop down, then It should display
Both CUT and PRESS.

Final Out Put should as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the advanced Editor, you can use this M Code:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUXIODQGSAUGuwcFAGoRidaKVjOAyQOTo4gITN4ZzXVx9PMNcg5D0mCCZg6EmNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, #"Owner 1" = _t, #"Owner 2" = _t, #"Owner 3" = _t, #"Owner 4" = _t]),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "OwnerShip"}, {"Value", "Owner"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"ID", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Let's explain step by step:

1st Stage : Your Source Data:

[image]

2nd Stage : Unpivot Columns except [ID] Column

Select ID column, go to Transform > Click Dropdown > Select Unpivot Other Columns

[image: 23]

3rd Stage:
Name your columns, change data types , finally and import your data:

Final Shape should appear like this:

[image: sd]

Then you can freely filter the owner column, let's select. cut:

You can see: ID (1,2) appears.

[image: ID1_1]

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is wrong for what you're trying to do, but it's a super easy fix. If you unpivot your table and remove the blanks, then you end up with just (ID, Owner, Action). then you can just drop a table onto your canvas and put any/all of the columns in it. And then add a slicer and add Action to it. Then if you select "Cut" from it, only the "Cut" items show.

Comment: Appreciate if you can share some samples.  :)